# i got the message top of the twillio that "You're limited to 50 daily messages. New Subaccounts can't be added. what is the root cause of this issue

Tags: push-notification, notifications, sms, push

i got the message top of the twillio that "You're limited to 50 daily messages. New Subaccounts can't be added. what is the root cause of this issue.

i raised a support ticket for the same.also check all logs but did not find any thing.one thing i found which i am attaching.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXNoc.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.